# Java Swing - jComboBox not refreshing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have an issue with my jComboBox not reflecting the changes in the model ...

In the model I have `Box` class that keeps an array list of `Item`s. I have a combo box model defined this way :

```
myCombo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(box.items().toArray()));
```

(I use NetBeans 'design' mode). So as far as I understand, after setting the model this way, the combo box should reflect any changes in `items` list and at the start of the application, it indeed correctly shows the elements of the `item` list.

I also have a button Add to add a random instance of `Item` to the `items` list.

```
    private void buttonAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    box.addRandomItem();
}
```

The method `addRandomItem()` simply adds some new instance of `Item` to the `items` list. So when I click the Add button, the new random item is correctly added to the `items` list (I can see it printed at the console) but at the GUI level, the list in combo box is not being updated so I cannot see the newly added item in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the new item manually to the model using `addElement(E element)` or `insertElementAt(E element, int index)`.

Internally, the `DefaultComboBoxModel` makes a copy of the items you provide as a parameter in the constructor, so there isn't any way to know that the original array has changed.